# Rank of $DH(x,x^{\prime})$ where $H$ does not depend on $x^\prime$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, $\text{rank}(Df(x))=k.$
Now Define a function $H: \mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$, $H(x,x')=f(x)$.

Does $\text{rank}(DH(x,x^{\prime}))= \text{rank}(Df(x))$? Can I conclude that $\text{nullity}DH(x,x') = m+n-\text{rank}(Df(x))=m+n-k$?

Comment: Substitute $H(x,x')$ with its equal $f(x)$ in $DH(x,x')$ and you get $Df(x)$, so their ranks must be equal, too. What bothers you?

Comment: @Al.G. Maybe because the $DH(x,x')$ is not exactly $Df(x)$, since the domain changes.

Comment: Ah right. So the argument here is that the *codomain* (range) doesn't change, hence the ranks are the same?

Comment: @Al.G. I am unsure because I did not have experience working with $\text{Rank}(\cdot)$ applied to some abstract functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue in a few steps. First, look that
\begin{align}
H(x + h, x') &= f(x + h)\\ 
&= f(x) + Df(x)h + \varepsilon(h)\\
&= H(x, x') + Df(x)h + \varepsilon(h)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
   H(x, x' + k) = f(x) = H(x, x').
\end{align}
From this follows that
\begin{align}
H(x + h, x' + k) &= H(x, x' + k) + Df(x)h + \varepsilon(h)\\
&= H(x, x') + Df(x)h + \varepsilon(h).
\end{align}
Therefore, by the uniqueness of the derivative, $DH(x,x')(h,k) = Df(x)h$. From this one have $\text{rank}(DH(x,x')) = k$ and $\text{null}(DH(x,x')) = m + n - k$.